# Which HTML Elements Style Typography Different By Default?

Tags: css, html, tags, user-agent

The following list of elements default font-size in Chrome:

- h1 = font-size: 2em;
- h2 = font-size: 1.5em;
- h3 = font-size: 1.17em;
- h5 = font-size: 0.83em;
- h6 = font-size: 0.67em;
- small, sub, sup = font-size: smaller;

Is the above list complete or not?

I have a huge codebase with legacy styles and don't want to bring https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ in legacy code, because it is potentially dangerous to the styles residing there.

Comment: Why you need to know this? In my concept is a bad idea use tags instead css classes... Classes is more reusable, you can use mixins, variables... To do your work better and combine sizes with other styles :)

Comment: `<sub>` `<sup>`

Comment: you shouldn't use tags for styling, since it can potentially mess up your SEO values

Comment: @RamonSchmidtRocha I don't need to use them. I need to set them all to 1em by default on huge codebase. I don't want to bring https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ in legacy code, because its dangerous.

Comment: @IgorGolopolosovI I think there are only these tags for formatting html text
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp :)

Comment: `<big>` has long been invalid, but if used, the browser's default stylesheet will cause an increase in the font size

Answer (score 0):

The `<font>` tag is not supported anymore in HTML5, so use CSS instead.

```
h1 {
   font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

etc

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: This answer from a year ago now has nothing to do with this question edited yesterday you're right